# How to detect the length of array property using reflection only if it actually is an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I'm converting an object based on reflection like this.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

It produces the expected list of properties.

> {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[4]}
> [0]: {System.String Name}
> [1]: {System.Guid[] Ids}
> [2]: {System.String[] Tags}
> [3]: {System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean] Status}

Then, I want to clear the list of properties not in use, so I add the condition that a value of a property needs to differ from `null`.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties()
  .Where(a => a.GetValue(obj) != null)
```

It produces the expected result for atomary fields but not the arrays (as they're undefinably not `null`, only empty).

> {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>}
> [0]: {System.String Name}
> [1]: {System.Guid[] Ids}
> [2]: {System.String[] Tags}

I'm not sure how I should go about detecting non-null but empty array properties in order to exclude those. I can't simply cast to an array (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747572/how-do-i-deal-with-arrays-using-reflection)) because not every property is an array.

The closest approach I have is this piece of "work", which seems to be rather... undesired. It's got this distinct code smell going on.

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties()
  .Where(a => a.GetValue(obj) != null 
    && !(a.GetValue(obj) is Array && (a.GetValue(obj) as Array).Length == 0))
```

And as I try to create something with it using `Select(a=>a.GetValue(obj))` it gets even clunkier and more obviously in desperate need of improvement. I also noticed that whenever the array isn't empty, my mapping fails producing `System.String%5b%5d`, which will probably require me to additionally clunkify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a solution that's significantly different to yours, fundamentally it feels like it's a custom logic to determine whether a property value is "empty" or not.

Perhaps a pattern matched switch expression might make the code a little cleaner, however, for example:

```
var obj = new MyObject
{
    Name = "Test",
    Ids = new Guid[0],
    Tags = new[] { "t1" },
    Status = null
};

var values = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(obj))
    .Where(o => o switch {
        Array array => array.Length > 0,
        _ => o != null
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the condition by using pattern matching. It allows you to call `GetValue` only once

```cs
p => p.GetValue(obj) is not null and not IList { Count: 0 }
```

or with the slightly shorter version

```cs
p => p.GetValue(obj) is not (null or IList { Count: 0 })
```

I tested for `IList` instead of array. This includes arrays and also `ArrayList` and `List<T>`. Note that an array exposes its `Length` through the explicitly implemented `IList.Count` property as well. "explicitly implemented" means that this member is hidden or private unless view directly through the interface.

You could even test for the `ICollection` interface instead. This would include even more collections.

`IList { Count: 0 }` is a property pattern which tests whether the object is an `IList` having a `Count` of 0.

Together:

```cs
var result = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.GetValue(obj) is not (null or IList { Count: 0 }));
```

Note that this uses [logical patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) introduced in C# 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the code smell when working with this blind reflection is largely unavoidable (to the best of my knowledge) and rarely condenses into a tight block cleanly.

Your mapping seems to be sensitive to the exact property type given the `string[]` output, alluding to it being unable to unwrap collections without assistance.

To address both issues, I'd suggest a verbose enumerable helper where the collection handling specifics are immediately apparent to any future maintainers.

```csharp
static IEnumerable<(Type Type, IEnumerable Values)> GetPopulatedPropertyData(object obj)
{
    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
        if (value is Array a)
        {
            if (a.Length == 0) { continue; }
            yield return (prop.PropertyType.GetElementType()!, a);
        }
        // Future collections added in reverse hierarchial order here
        else if (value is not null)
        {
            yield return (prop.PropertyType, new[] { value });
        }
    }
}
```

This should facilitate mapping by making the correct type available while keeping the majority of the ugly code in its own box.